# Eclipse warning: "contains markers which may be removed by Sort Members" -- markers?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Sometimes when using 'Source > Sort Members' in Eclipse, I get this warning message.  I am assuming "markers" are referring to [these](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_markers.htm), but what is making them?

I don't manually make them.  Could a plugin, FindBugs or PMD, be making these markers?  (I still get the warning even when there are no current FindBugs or PMD warnings.)

I never visually see any indication of these "markers".  Is it safe to just ignore this warning?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Markers can be Errors, Warnings, Bookmarks, Todo tasks and anything else that plugins care to create. They are attached to a file and can specify a position in the file - the sort may have to discard them.

You can see all markers in the Markers view (Window > Show View > Other... > General > Markers). Errors and warnings are shown in the Problems view, Bookmarks in the Bookmarks view and Todo in the Tasks view.

Most markers on a file are also indicated in the vertical ruler on the left of the editor for the file.